# DbContextScope Transaction

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, dbcontext

I am using [mehdime/DbContextScope](https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope) as [documented here](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/) to implemeent a bulk user refresh/import solution for our product.

Under the heading "*Changes are only persisted when SaveChanges() is called*", Mehdi states in code sample:

> Do not call SaveChanges() until the business transaction is complete -
>   i.e. no partial or intermediate saves. SaveChanges() must be called
>   exactly once per business transaction.
>
> If you find yourself needing to call SaveChanges() multiple times
>   within a business transaction, it means that you are in fact
>   implementing multiple business transactions within a single service
>   method.

However, I want to add a new row, obtain its generated ID (IDENTITY column) and then add an audit log entry to the database referencing the generated ID.  To do this, I need to perform an intermediate `SaveChanges()` in order for EF to perform the INSERT and get an ID, however I want to do this in a single atomic transaction.

Am I missing something or is this actually possible without breaking the Medhi's rule?

Here is my code sample (which current breaks the rule)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Location
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="orgID">ID of Organisation</param>
    /// <param name="name">Location Name</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IActionResult Create(int orgID, string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

        // New Location
        var location = new Location {
            OrganisationID = orgID,
            Name = name,
            Enabled = true
        };

        using (var dbContextScope = _dbContextScopeFactory.Create())
        {
            var ctx = dbContextScope.DbContexts.Get<PlatformEntities2014>();

            // Duplicate name?
            var existing = ctx.Locations.Where(l => l.OrganisationID == orgID && l.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
            if (existing != null)
                return new ActionResult(ActionResultCode.ErrorAlreadyExists) { ReferencedObject = existing };

            ctx.Locations.Add(location);
            // ---POSITION A---
            dbContextScope.SaveChanges();   // (Assigns location.ID)

            // Log
            GeneralLog log = new GeneralLog() {
                DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                Code = "LOC",
                SubCode = "NEW",
                OrganisationID = orgID,
                Information = $"Location {location.ID} \"{location.Name}\" created during Bulk Refresh."
            };
            ctx.GeneralLogs.Add(log);
            // ---POSITION B---
            dbContextScope.SaveChanges();

            return new ActionResult(ActionResultCode.Success) { ReferencedObject = location };
        }
    }
```

Would it be acceptable to replace the first `dbContextScope.SaveChanges();` at **POSITION A** with `ctx.SaveChanges();` to obtain the ID and call `dbContextScope.SaveChanges();` at the **POSITION B**?

Thanks.

Comment: How are your EF relationships set up within the context. If they are setup correctly as in location is related to log via foreign key relationship. You can just call the savechanges() at position 2 and EF should auto plugin the IDs for you.

Comment: @Preet, unfortunately, as you can see from the code sample, the `GeneralLog` table is a generic log and doesn't have a direct relation with the `Location` table - we want to log the Location's ID and Name in the `Information varchar(...)` field.  The `GeneralLog` records lots of information about lots of different things and isn't `Location` specific.  I do understand your suggest but no relationship exists in this case.

Comment: Should have read it a bit better. Ok in that case these are 2 separate business transactions. Look at it this way your transaction is not considered as failed if it fails to create a 'GeneralLog'. Hence I would say do it as 2 separate transactions.

Comment: @Preet: Good point.  I should consider this option then.  Maybe add all my Locations and other objects in one transaction and then do a second transaction to add all my Log entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further on from your explanation of what the relationships are in comments. these are 2 separate business transactions. Look at it this way your transaction is not considered as failed if it fails to create a 'GeneralLog'. Hence I would say do it as 2 separate transactions. Logging should not fail your business transaction. What you can do is create the objects first in one transaction. The get the IDs and create logs in a separate transaction.